# python configparser map section values to other sections

Tags: python, configparser

I'd like to be able to read a variable list of files from a config file section and use the keys from that list to point to further sections that define attributes for each file. The files can change in number and name and attributes. Has anyone seen any method of doing this or can point me in the right direction?

```
[paths]
file1=/some/path/
file2=/some/other/path

[file1]
key_specific_to_file_1=some_attribute_value

[file2]
key_specific_to_file_2=some_attribute_value2

[non-file-related-section]
some_key=some-other-value
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what needs to be done?

Comment: Good question... I think was over analyzing this. I guess I can just get a list of the keys in the [paths] section. Sometimes it really is that simple...

Answer (score 0):

there is standard module configparser. documentation can be found [configparser documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

simple example :

```
    #/usr/bin/env python
    import configparser
    import sys

    def config_reader(filename):
        try:
            config = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config.read(filename )
            section_list = config.sections()
            for section_name in section_list:
                for key in config[section_name]:
                    print("Key : " +  config[section_name ][key])
        except configparser.Error as e:
            print(e)
            return 

    def main():
        print("config file " + sys.argv[1])
        config_reader(sys.argv[1])


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Note:  this example is based on Python 3; it does not work for 2.x